# Stopping and starting a slideshow with onclick event

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I want to control this slideshow to start/stop using onclick on #mainImage. At this point, I can get the slides to stop, but I'm stuck on the logic for how to use onclick to start it again. Ideally, I want the slideshow to continue from the array position where it left off as opposed to starting over completely. My instinct tells me this could be solved with some conditional statements, but I just can't get it to work. Thanks for any feedback!

```
//Grab img 
var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

//Create image array
var imageArray = ["images/drifter.jpg","images/drifter3.jpg","images/drifter4.jpg"];

//Set up array index
var imageIndex = 0;

//Create function to cycle through images
function changeImage() {
    mainImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}

//Call cycle function
var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,3000);

mainImage.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a flag to know when it stopped and when should continue

```
//Grab img 
var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

//Create image array
var imageArray = ["images/drifter.jpg","images/drifter3.jpg","images/drifter4.jpg"];

//Set up array index
var imageIndex = 0;
// here the flag
var stop = false;

//Create function to cycle through images
function changeImage() {
    mainImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}

//Call cycle function
var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,3000);

mainImage.onclick = function () {
    if(!stop){
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);  
        stop = true;
    } else {
        intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,3000);
        stop = false;
    }
}
```